# error using IF statement

Tags: microsoft-excel

Whenever I am trying to input this on excel:

[image]

```
 =IF(MOD([@[charm_slot_no]],13)<> 0,["Charm" & QUOTIENT([@[charm_slot_no]],13)+1 & "-" & MOD([@[charm_slot_no]],13)], ["Charm" & QUOTIENT([@[charm_slot_no]],13)+1 & "-" & MOD([@[charm_slot_no]],13)+1])
```

I get this error issue:

[image]

charm_slot_no was just one the columns I had. I'm not sure what they mean by incorrect name, if anyone could help me with this. This is probably way more complicated than it should be, but I don't see why I can't input anything.

Comment: Are you trying to make a column name by using the `[]` around `"Charm" & QUOTIENT([@[charm_slot_no]],13)+1 & "-" & MOD([@[charm_slot_no]],13)`?  Those are what is leading to the error.

Comment: Yeah that turned out to be the issue. I was trying to put my 'value_if_true' inside ```[]```. I changed it into normal brackets and it worked. Thank you so much!